# How to set up independent variable (x) in the fisrt column in R?

Tags: r, datatable

When I see the built-in data in R,

View(state.x77)

[image]

I see the independent variable (States) is located in the first column in R table.

When I generate data

```
Genotype<- c("A","B","C","D","E")
KN<- c(616,576,615,590,606)
KW<- c(335.5,359.8,335.6,357.8,333.3)
COB<- c(242.5,237.2,234.3,243.8,232.6)
dataA<- data.frame(Genotype,KN,KW,COB)
```

Data table is like below. I want Genotype to be located in the first column like `state.x77` data.

[image]

Could you tell me how to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: It is actually `row.names`.  You may use `row.names(dataA) <- Genotype` where `dataA <- data.frame(KN,KW,COB)`

Comment: `rownames(dataA) <- dataA[, 1]`